# How To Solve Failed host lookup: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I don't Know The Problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMFu5.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check whether you have internet connection or not.
2. Check if you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml
3. If you are using emulator, make sure emulator has internet connection